# PHP PDO SQL only returning one row of data instead of all rows

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I am using PHP PDO extension to create a list of all items from a DB category table.
The expected results are not correct, only one row of data returned instead of all 
rows which is expected.
By running the same SQL statement within the phpMyAdmin console I get the expected 
results for all rows of data.
I need to know what I am overlooking with pdo.

Current code:

```
    $catId = 0;   

    $sql = "SELECT *
            FROM category
            WHERE cat_parent_id = :catId
            ORDER BY cat_name";

    $_stmt = $this->_dbConn->prepare($sql);
    $_stmt->bindParam(":catId", $catId, PDO::PARAM_INT);  
    $_stmt->execute();

    $rows = $_stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);    

    // display PDO result - only getting one row instead of all rows.       
    print_r($rows);

    Array ( [cat_id] => 3 
            [cat_parent_id] => 0 
            [cat_name] => Shop 
            [cat_description] => Seminars 
            [cat_image] => c72e.gif 
            )

    // NOTE: By running the same SQL within the phpMyAdmin 
    // console I get the expected results with all rows.
    Array ( [cat_id] => 3 
            [cat_parent_id] => 0 
            [cat_name] => Shop 
            [cat_description] => Seminars 
            [cat_image] => c72e.gif 
           ),
          ( [cat_id] => 1 
            [cat_parent_id] => 0 
            [cat_name] => Site Map 
            [cat_description] => List content links 
            [cat_image] => c83b.gif 
           )
```

Comment: `WHERE cat_parent_id = :catId`

Comment: `fetch()` or `fetchAll()`? the former returns one row, the latter all rows. Use `fetch` in a loop

Answer (score 4):

[`PDOStatement::fetch()`](https://php.net/manual/pdostatement.fetch.php) will only return 1 row at a time.

You could use [`PDOStatement::fetchAll()`](https://php.net/manual/pdostatement.fetchall.php):

```
$rows = $_stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

or create a loop where you keep calling `PDOStatement::fetch()` until it returns `false`:

```
$rows = array();
while( $row = $_stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC) ) {
  $rows[] = $row;
}
```

But the latter example is a bit redundant, if you want to get all rows at once anyway, unless there are some memory concerns you want to address.

Comment: The `fetch()` was the bummer!  Everything is now working as expected.  Thanks for the quick response.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use fetchAll like below:

```
$rows = $_stmt->fetchAll();
print_r($rows);
```